# How to use 2 variables in a function instead of 1 to webs scrape sub-URLs in power bi and power query?

Tags: function, web-scraping, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I Have this table;

[image]

that was created using this code;

```
let
    Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("https://www.edmunds.com/sitemap_web54-mmy-cost-to-own.xml")),
    Table0 = Source{0}[Table],
    #"Kept First Rows" = Table.FirstN(Table0,10),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Kept First Rows", "Custom", each Web.BrowserContents([loc])),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.3", each try Text.Range([Custom],Text.PositionOf([Custom],"<optgroup"),Text.PositionOf([Custom],"</optgroup>")-Text.PositionOf([Custom],"<optgroup")+11) otherwise "<optgroup/>"),
    #"Parsed XML" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom3",{{"Custom.3", Xml.Tables}}),
    #"Expanded Custom.3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Parsed XML", "Custom.3", {"option"}, {"option"}),
    #"Expanded option" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded Custom.3", "option", {"Element:Text", "Attribute:value"}, {"Model", "Style"})
in
    #"Expanded option"
```

If you look at the `loc` column you will see that there is the same link for multiple models.
**Ultimately** I want the *Cost to Own* data for each model.
So I created this code in a new query and tied it to a custom column in the above query.

```
(PageMake as text)=>
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents(PageMake),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", "SECTION:nth-child(2) > DIV.table-responsive > TABLE.costs-table.text-gray-darker.table.table-borderless > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, {"Column2", "SECTION:nth-child(2) > DIV.table-responsive > TABLE.costs-table.text-gray-darker.table.table-borderless > * > TR > :nth-child(2)"}, {"Column3", "SECTION:nth-child(2) > DIV.table-responsive > TABLE.costs-table.text-gray-darker.table.table-borderless > * > TR > :nth-child(3)"}, {"Column4", "SECTION:nth-child(2) > DIV.table-responsive > TABLE.costs-table.text-gray-darker.table.table-borderless > * > TR > :nth-child(4)"}, {"Column5", "SECTION:nth-child(2) > DIV.table-responsive > TABLE.costs-table.text-gray-darker.table.table-borderless > * > TR > :nth-child(5)"}, {"Column6", "SECTION:nth-child(2) > DIV.table-responsive > TABLE.costs-table.text-gray-darker.table.table-borderless > * > TR > :nth-child(6)"}, {"Column7", "SECTION:nth-child(2) > DIV.table-responsive > TABLE.costs-table.text-gray-darker.table.table-borderless > * > TR > :nth-child(7)"}}, [RowSelector="SECTION:nth-child(2) > DIV.table-responsive > TABLE.costs-table.text-gray-darker.table.table-borderless > * > TR"]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Extracted Table From Html", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"", type text}, {"Year 1", Currency.Type}, {"Year 2", Currency.Type}, {"Year 3", Currency.Type}, {"Year 4", Currency.Type}, {"Year 5", Currency.Type}, {"Total", Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

The problem is that the link does not have any tie to the different models so when it pulls the *Cost to Own* data table it simply pulls the first one for all models associated with that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that there is not a distinct table for each vehicle. There is one table shared by several. If you do a new web query (Query -> Web) and enter a URL like `https://www.edmunds.com/lexus/ls-460/2016/cost-to-own/?style=401580678` you'll see the collection of tables. (I'm quite sure you already know this from your info above.) But if you look within the Suggested Tables, you'll see they all contain information for multiple 2016 models. I think you'll need to pull the entire table with the information you want (I think you want Table 1) and then parse that table once you get it. You can use any one of the vehicles from that table to get to the table. (It appears to me, from a quick glance, that each table is all of the vehicles from the year group).

Call your function from a new column in your first query with `= Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded option", "Custom.1", each fnGetEdmunds(Text.From([loc])&"?style="&Text.From([Style])))`. You'll get some errors because some rows don't have Styles to find pages with the Cost to Own and some of the pages don't have tables with Cost to Own. So you'll have to handle those errors.

Here's M code:

```
//The base query:
let
    Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("https://www.edmunds.com/sitemap_web54-mmy-cost-to-own.xml")),
    Table0 = Source{0}[Table],
    #"Kept First Rows" = Table.FirstN(Table0,10),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Kept First Rows", "Custom", each Web.BrowserContents([loc])),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.3", each try Text.Range([Custom],Text.PositionOf([Custom],"<optgroup"),Text.PositionOf([Custom],"</optgroup>")-Text.PositionOf([Custom],"<optgroup")+11) otherwise "<optgroup/>"),
    #"Parsed XML" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom3",{{"Custom.3", Xml.Tables}}),
    #"Expanded Custom.3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Parsed XML", "Custom.3", {"option"}, {"option"}),
    #"Expanded option" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded Custom.3", "option", {"Element:Text", "Attribute:value"}, {"Model", "Style"}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded option", "Custom.1", each fnGetEdmunds(Text.From([loc])&"?style="&Text.From([Style])))
in
    #"Invoked Custom Function"

//The function named fnGetEdmunds
(PageMake as text)=>
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents(PageMake),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", ".col-fixed"}, {"Column2", ".col-padding-left"}, {"Column3", ".col-padding-left + *"}, {"Column4", ".d-none TD:nth-child(4)"}, {"Column5", ".d-none TD:nth-child(5)"}, {"Column6", ".d-none TD:nth-child(6)"}, {"Column7", ".d-none .font-weight-bold"}, {"Column8", ".d-none:nth-child(3) TD:nth-child(4)"}, {"Column9", ".d-none:nth-child(3) TD:nth-child(5)"}, {"Column10", ".d-none:nth-child(3) TD:nth-child(6)"}, {"Column11", ".d-none:nth-child(4) TD:nth-child(4)"}, {"Column12", ".d-none:nth-child(4) TD:nth-child(5)"}, {"Column13", ".d-none:nth-child(4) TD:nth-child(6)"}, {"Column14", ".d-none:nth-child(5) TD:nth-child(4)"}, {"Column15", ".d-none:nth-child(5) TD:nth-child(5)"}, {"Column16", ".d-none:nth-child(5) TD:nth-child(6)"}, {"Column17", ".d-inline"}, {"Column18", ".p-0.heading-4"}, {"Column19", ".mb-1 SPAN"}, {"Column20", "CAPTION"}, {"Column21", "TH:nth-child(4)"}, {"Column22", "TH:nth-child(5)"}, {"Column23", "TH:nth-child(6)"}, {"Column24", "TH:nth-child(7)"}}, [RowSelector=".col-fixed"]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Extracted Table From Html", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"", type text}, {"Year 1", type text}, {"Year 2", type text}, {"Column4", Currency.Type}, {"Column5", Currency.Type}, {"Column6", Currency.Type}, {"Column7", Currency.Type}, {"Column8", Currency.Type}, {"Column9", Currency.Type}, {"Column10", Currency.Type}, {"Column11", Currency.Type}, {"Column12", Currency.Type}, {"Column13", Currency.Type}, {"Column14", Currency.Type}, {"Column15", Currency.Type}, {"Column16", Currency.Type}, {"Column17", type text}, {"Column18", type text}, {"Column19", type text}, {"Column20", type text}, {"Year 3", type text}, {"Year 4", type text}, {"Year 5", type text}, {"Total", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Like I said above: You'll still need to parse the tables to extract the info for the specific vehicles, and to handle the errors.

Comment: Some did throw an error like you said because there was no data but this one threw an error even when there was data https://www.edmunds.com/lexus/ls-460/2016/cost-to-own/?style=401580677

Comment: It doesn't throw an error for me. I get a table.